# Installing PostGIS on older homebrew versions of PostgreSQL (e.g. postgresql@9.6)?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, homebrew

**As there are two ways to solve this question, I asked for another approach [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/261526/23119).**

Whenever a major release of PostgreSQL appears, [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) will happily install it right away, unless one [pins](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-stop-certain-formulae-from-being-updated) a certain version or [installs a specific version from `Homebrew/core`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/2075003).

So far so good, but the problem is that PostGIS also keeps updating and eventually will be incompatible with pinned or `Homebrew/core` versions of PostgreSQL. Again, one can pin PostGIS, yet `Homebrew/core` does not offer previous versions. From time to time I do `brew cleanup` and somehow I am now left with a broken PostGIS database. Ok, so "time to jump to PostgreSQL 10.1", I though, but [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) now gets stuck with the error

> ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory

That means I can't back nor forth: I cannot figure out how to get PostGIS working with `postgresql@9.6` and I cannot pg_upgrade to the new version of PostgreSQL (10.1).

Therefore my question can be answered in two ways. Here I am asking:

*How to install PostGIS with older PostgreSQL versions, i.e. `postgresql@9.6`, using homebrew?*

The second approach is described at [Upgrading PostgreSQL with broken PostGIS installation ("$libdir/postgis-2.3" error)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/261526/23119)

---

Tried so far:

- [This gist](https://gist.github.com/gopperman/18cb66078372d3261420829630230b80) offers a solution and it might actually work. However, I had to use `ln -s` instead of `cp -a`. It seems to be working now, but unfortunately I have the problem that my database is already on 2.4 and there seems to be no downgrade path. Will keep trying.

Comment: **Using** PostGIS can certainly be a GIS topic, but trying to defeat installation/upgrade tools seems more like an OS task, unrelated to our charter.

Comment: @Vince Funny you say that. I [keep getting such comments](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4490/23119) here, although GIS SE is full with such questions. There is even a `homebrew` tag. Anyway, please move it if you think this is appropriate.

Comment: P.S.: Just added the `installation` tag as well... @Vince

Comment: To the people in favor of closing the question, please [participate in the discussion](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4760/23119) if installation-related questions are on-topic. Dear downvoters, please give me an indication how to improve my question!

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, installing Postgres 9.6.10 and PostGIS 2.4: https://github.com/CloverHealth/homebrew-tap