# Upgrading PostgreSQL with broken PostGIS installation ("$libdir/postgis-2.3" error)?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, homebrew

**As there are two ways to solve this question, I asked for another approach [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/261525/23119).**

Whenever a major release of PostgreSQL appears, [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) will happily install it right away, unless one [pins](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-stop-certain-formulae-from-being-updated) a certain version or [installs a specific version from `Homebrew/core`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/2075003).

So far so good, but the problem is that PostGIS also keeps updating and eventually will be incompatible with pinned or `Homebrew/core` versions of PostgreSQL. Again, one can pin PostGIS, yet `Homebrew/core` does not offer previous versions. From time to time I do `brew cleanup` and somehow I am now left with a broken PostGIS database. Ok, so "time to jump to PostgreSQL 10.1", I though, but [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) now gets stuck with the error

> ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory

That means I can't back nor forth: I cannot figure out how to get PostGIS working with `postgresql@9.6` and I cannot pg_upgrade to the new version of PostgreSQL (10.1).

Therefore my question can be answered in two ways. Here I am asking:

*How to upgrade PostgeSQL with a broken PostGIS installation ("$libdir/postgis-2.3" error)?*

The second approach is described at [Installing PostGIS on older homebrew versions of PostgreSQL (e.g. postgresql@9.6)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/261525/23119)

---

What I tried so far:

- `DROP EXTENSION postgis;` does not work because the geo-spatial tables depend on it. I could `DROP CASCADE` but this would probably delete my tables and I would like to preserve them.

Comment: **Using** PostGIS can certainly be a GIS topic, but trying to defeat installation/upgrade tools seems more like an OS task, unrelated to our charter.

Comment: @Vince Funny you say that. I [keep getting such comments](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4490/23119) here, although GIS SE is full with such questions. There is even a `homebrew` tag. Anyway, please move it if you think this is appropriate.

Comment: To the people in favor of closing the question, please [participate in the discussion](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4760/23119) if installation-related questions are on-topic. Dear downvoters, please give me an indication how to improve my question!

Answer (score 2):

After a whole day of trial & error, I found one possible solution.

The PostGIS website describes the [hard upgrade](http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade) path, which boils down to the following steps:

1. Dump the entire database

   > pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f "/somepath/olddb.backup" olddb
2. Initialize and enable PostGIS on the new database.
3. Run the restore utility

   > perl utils/postgis_restore.pl "/somepath/olddb.backup" | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres newdb 2> errors.txt

In my case the dump (in step 1) would not work at first because the upgrade to PostGIS 2.4 had apparently failed at some point. The problem is apparently that the PostGIS releases are specific to a PostgreSQL database release as discussed [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/996). Luckily, there was for a short time a release of PostGIS 2.4.0 that I could re-enable by means of `brew switch postgis 2.4.0` (the current version is called 2.4.0_1). In case you have a similar problem, you may be able to pull the correct version from github. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/gopperman/18cb66078372d3261420829630230b80) may also give you some food for thought.

I am still not sure what the regular upgrade procedure would look like.

Answer (score 1):

I covered this issue in this article.

http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/268-Using-pg_upgrade-to-upgrade-PostGIS-without-installing-an-older-version-of-PostGIS.html

In a nutshell, PostGIS 2.4 only adds in new functions, so you can simply copy your postgis-2.4.*, rtpostgis-2.4.* and call it postgis-2.3.*, rtpostgis-2.3.* in your new instance.

and then pg_upgrade will work fine because it will find the postgis-2.3 and rtpostgis-2.3 libs with all the functions present in the old postgis-2.3 / rtpostgis-2.3 libs.

Comment: should that approach still work for postgis 2.3.2 -> 2.5.0 on mac os x? I've run into the same problem having running brew install to go from postgres 9.6.1 to 10.5 as my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253267/missing-postgis-causing-pg-upgrade-to-fail-on-mac-os-x